# Weakening of weak Lefschetz theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Is there some sort of general condition that implies for a closed immersion of projective complex varieties $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$, the map on the $n$-th homology sends non $p$-divisible elements to non $p$-divisible ones? I am particularly interested in the non-torsion elements i.e. for the generators of the non-torsion part of $H_n(Z)$ their image is either torsion or non $p$-divisible non-torsion. (for some prime $p$)

This is a weakening of the weak Lefschetz which gives us an isomorphism on the homology, so I am expecting the conditions for something like this to be much more relaxed than the Lefschetz's theorem, for example I am interested in the cases where the varieties are not necessarily smooth or irreducible.

Another situation that this can happen is when the homology of the closed sub-variety split injects into the homology of the larger variety. Are there conditions studying when this kind of split injection can happen? (for example when the closed sub-variety is a retract of the larger one.)